# PHP: How to dividebythree

Tags: php

I'm doing a little PHP activity but I'm having some trouble. What I need to do is I need to dividebythree for 99 bottles of beer (multiple of 3, so 99, 96, 93 etc are multiples of 3, but 98, 97, 95 etc are not multiples of 3). I start from 99 and go all they way down to one. However, with my current code, it's an infinite loop. It starts at 99, but instead of going all the way down to one, it continues with the next number (100, 101, 102 etc.) and continues on. What are some pointers that I can fix my program?

```
</head>
<body>
    <?php

    //$beerBottles = 99;

    for($beerBottles = 99; $beerBottles >=0; $beerBottles++)
    {
        //echo “Loop Started; value is $value”;

        if($beerBottles % 3 == 0)
        {
            echo $beerBottles . ' bottles is a multiple of 3... ';
            echo '<br />';
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            echo $beerBottles . ' bottles is NOT a multiple of 3... ';
            echo '<br />';
        }
    }
    ?>
</body> </html>
```

Comment: Jesus. Why don't people try to understand the code they copy&paste before asking...

Answer (score 1):

You're using `$beerBottles++`, which increments the variable by 1. You should be using `$beerBottles--` <sup><sub>(or `--$beerBottles` if you care about micro-optimalizations)</sub></sup> to decrement it by 1 if you want it to go down instead of up.

Comment: Man I feel really stupid. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

//$beerBottles = 99;

for($beerBottles = 99; $beerBottles >=0; $beerBottles--)
{
    //echo “Loop Started; value is $value”;

    if($beerBottles % 3 == 0)
    {
        echo $beerBottles . ' bottles is a multiple of 3... ';
        echo '<br />';
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        echo $beerBottles . ' bottles is NOT a multiple of 3... ';
        echo '<br />';
    }
}
?>
```

Use `--` instead of `++` in the `for` loop.

Comment: Please format this as code (indent each line for spaces, or use the button for code). Also please explain your solution instead of dumping code in here, so that others can understand and learn from it.